# Architecture, Logging user activity on rest backend server for handle custom user UI

Tags: database, rest

I want to make logging module user activity on the rest backend server.
Our web service's UI transform with user activity histories.

Example,
There is Users and Projects.(User - Project(M:N))

User's projects list be sorted by recent clicked project.
I can make something like below for versatility,
// Make userAction table that has this scheme.

```
{ user_id: 1, targetDocument_id: 2, action: 'view', targetEntity: 'project', createdAt: '2022-06-29 08:22',...}
```

If the user requests their project list, I query the userAction table and manually sort.
Or, I can make this function easily with add custom fields to the project table.
But I think there is better practice for like this purpose.
Isn't it?
Any advice..?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it fast enough? With indexes? Then keep what you have. Don't optimize if you don't need to.

If you find that this approach is unacceptably slow, you could denormalize the data and create a table like:

```
user_id
project_id
last_access_time
```

You probably already have a table with the first 2 fields, so adding a new field will make this *very* fast.

Do you need to denormalize? It depends on the size of the data and what scale you're expecting. If you have lots of users and generating tons of log entries I suspect that the denormalized approach quickly becomes desirable, but if you have 1 user that uses the application a few times per week you may never get there.

There is a cost to denormalizing. It's more code, and it duplicates data, so use it when you (think) there's a benefit.

Comment: Thank you Evert, I should described what is want more specifically,
I want that table(or module) to use more universally(like logging **every** action of user ).
But I am not sure that structure ```{ user_id: 1, targetDocument_id: 2, action: 'view', targetEntity: 'project', createdAt: '2022-06-29 08:22',...}```.

Comment: @yusunglee what part are you unsure about?

Comment: I think, 'logging every user actions' is common task for commercial service.
But I have no experience of that action of commercial service.
So, maybe I guess there is a more typical(solid) architecture logging user action for customized UI.

Comment: @yusunglee No I think you're on the right path. Make proper database fields for all the info that appears in all messages (user_id, time, message_type), and create a JSON field for all information you don't care to search for and could be different per message type. There are better log storage systems once you hit a very large scale, but until you hit a billion records you're probably safe.